# Fiber of map to $\mathbb{P}^1$ and linear equivalency

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Suppose that $X$ is a curve and $f\in K(X)$. Then $f$ can be realized as a map $f:X\to\mathbb{P}^1$ given by $x\mapsto[f(x):1]$. My question is: if we take any point $a\in\mathbb{P}^1$, are the points in the fiber $f^{-1}(a)$ linearly equivalent as divisors?

Suppose $P_1,P_2$ are two divisors in $f^{-1}(a)$. Then I want that $P_1-P_2=\sum v_p(f)P$, but I'm not sure how to get this from the fact that $P_1,P_2$ both map to $a$. What am I missing?

Comment: No? Consider the case of an elliptic curve $E: y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ and the function $f(x,y)=x$?

Comment: @Aphelli Is there anything one can say about fibers of a map to $\mathbb{P}^1$ and linear equivalent divisors?

Comment: The correct thing to say is thay for any two points in $\Bbb P^1$ the fibers over those two points are linearly equivalent as divisors. The proof is not hard: the rational function with a zero at one of the points and a pole at the other pulls back to a rational function with zeroes on one fiber and poles on the other.

Comment: Also, if you have a (smooth) curve and distinct points $P, Q$ are linearly equivalent, then $X$ is rational. Indeed; a rational function $f$ with a zero at $P$ and a pole at $Q$ would induce a degree 1 morphism (ie. an isomorphism), $X \to \mathbb{P}^1$. Because of this, your condition could only hold if all maps $X \to \mathbb{P}^1$, with $g > 0$, are injective.